# Ionic + Firebase redundant storing of data

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

JS:

```
angular.module('ShareGoalsApp')

.controller('newGoalCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $firebaseArray) {

    var goal_collection = new Firebase("https://sharegoals.firebaseio.com/sharegoals");
    $scope.goals = $firebaseArray(goal_collection);


    $scope.addNewGoal = function(goals) {
        $scope.goals.$add(goals);
    };
});
```

HTML related to the controller above:

```
<ion-pane view-title="goal">
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
          <a nav-transition="android" class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-left-b" ng-click="" href="#/index"></a>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Add New Goal</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>


    <ion-content class="padding has-header has-footer" scroll="false" >
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="#Title" ng-model="goals.gTitle">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="hashtag-title">#{{goals.gTitle}}</span>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <textarea placeholder="Goal" ng-model="goals.gDescription"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
    </ion-content>


    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
        <button class="button button-positive button-bar no-round-corner" ng-click="addNewGoal(goals)">Add Goal</button>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-pane>
```

what happens to firebase is this:

```
[id]
name: "value1"

[id2]
0
    name: "value1"
name2: "value2"

[id3]
0
    name: "value1"
1
    name2: "value2"
name3: "value3"
```

as it adds new data... it fetches the data before it and then adds it to the new one... it has now redundant values throughout the firebase storage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in your addNewGoal method. First you get the entire array of goals using 
    `$scope.goals = $firebaseArray(goal_collection);`

And when you call addNewGoal you give that same array to the function and it is being added to the array when you use `$scope.goals.$add(goals);`

If you only want to add a single new goal i suggest using a seperate $scope variable for that new goal and pass that to the addNewGoal function, that should work.